# How to build self-contained executable with gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

In order to do some compiler evaluation work I need to be able to build executables on a current Linux platform with recent versions of gcc/clang, and then copy these executables to an older Linux platform for testing and benchmarking. Of course this doesn't work because the older platform has older versions of various required shared libraries. So far I've tried:

- copy various required .so libraries to the destination system and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so that they get picked up - this results in errors such as:

> ./foo: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by ./foo)

and then when these get resolved by adding more .so files then I end up with:

> ls: relocation error: ./libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference

- I also tried using `-static` when linking, but then various libraries are not found and linking fails (presumably because many libraries exist only in shared form)

I found one possible solution in various old (similar, but not duplicate) StackOverflow questions (e.g. [Compile shared library into a program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901046/compile-shared-library-into-a-program/9674040)), but this approach seems very convoluted - it requires following all the library dependencies and converting them to static libraries. Ironically the tools used in these solutions are apparently only available as closed source binaries.

It seems this must be a common problem - otherwise how do people distribute binary-only applications ? Am I missing a simpler solution here ?

---

### UPDATE

I just tried the [trial version of Magic Ermine](http://magicermine.com/trial/ErmineLightTrial.x86_64/ErmineLightTrial.x86_64/ErmineLightTrial.x86_64.html) and it works as advertised. Since this is only a short-term requirement I will probably stick with this solution, but see comments below for alternate suggestions. Also see the free tool [statifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/statifier) from the same author as Magic Ermine. I'm closing this question as a duplicate now, but leaving it here for any future visitors.

Comment: Try to link just libc statically.

Comment: @n.m.: I don't think that's going to be enough, but I'll try it.

Comment: You should also install the header files for the versions of the libraries you use in a private include directory, and compile with `--sysroot=…`.  You will need to do this with at least `libc`.  If you have the source for the libraries you’re using, you can build the newer versions of the static libraries.  Make sure to build them against the libraries in your cross-compilation `--sysroot`.

Comment: Alternatively, `-static -nostdlib -lc -lm -lgcc` might work for you, if the version of the other system isn't running on a kernel too much older.  It will produce a very large executable, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I don't mind how big the executable is, since this is only for evaluation/benchmarking purposes. I may give your idea a try later, but I'm having some success currently with the trial version of Magic Ermine light, so that may be an easier solution.